Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code
I recently did a bunch of UrlMappings refactoring in my grails app.
Now I am getting the following error, and I am not even sure where to dig into.
I have rechecked everything I could. Even reverted the UrlMappings files I changes. Still getting the same error:
''2024-04-14 14:10:15.533  WARN --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.cache                  : HHH90001006: Missing cache[priz.api.tools.forty_principles.MatrixElement] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.cache.ehcache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.616 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.647 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.675 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.706 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.725 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.766 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.778 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.789 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.825 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.850 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.860 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.868 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.877 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.918 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.938 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:18.994 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:19.008 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:19.024 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:19.045 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:19.064 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] ultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder : Mapping: 'projectId' does not start with / or is response code.
''2024-04-14 14:10:19.080  WARN --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsErrorPageCustomizer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'urlMappings'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean property 'targetSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsTargetSource': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3e406925' of type [org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e406925': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.web.mapping.UrlMapping.projectId() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[matches:\d+]]
'Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52482', transport: 'socket'
'2024-04-14 14:10:19.203 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

How do I even find where the problem is in that case?

I am blind!!!
Apparently, I had one of my URLs defined with a constraint on projectId but the URL itself didn't have this parameter.
